# Add slide image with css

Tags: html, css, slider

**How to add 1 more image and animation for this slider**. please help me to change value property @-moz-keyframes{} or @-webkit-keyframes{}. thanks.

there my slider https://jsfiddle.net/JonoRecher/zt3d2duj/

```css
/* MY CSS*/
#wrapper4 {
  border-top: 7px solid #bdbdbd;
  border-bottom: 7px solid #bdbdbd;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  background-image: url(http://subtlepatterns2015.subtlepatterns.netdna-cdn.com/patterns/congruent_outline.png);
}

#slider4 {
  background: #000;
  border: 5px solid #eaeaea;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  height: 320px;
  width: 680px;
  margin: 0 auto 0;
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
}

#mask {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 320px;
}

#slider4 ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

#slider4 li {
  width: 640px;
  height: 320px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -325px;
  list-style: none;
}

#slider4 li.animation1 {
  animation: cycle 25s linear infinite;
}

#slider4 li.animation2 {
  animation: cycle2 25s linear infinite;
}

#slider4 li.animation3 {
  animation: cycle3 25s linear infinite;
}

#slider4 li.animation4 {
  animation: cycle4 25s linear infinite;
}

#slider4 li.animation5 {
  animation: cycle5 25s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes cycle {
  0% {top: 0px;}
  4% {top: 0px;}
  16% {top: 0px;opacity: 1;z-index: 0;}
  20% {top: 325px;opacity: 0;z-index: 0;}
  21% {top: -325px;opacity: 0;z-index: -1;}
  92% {top: -325px;opacity: 0;z-index: 0;}
  96% { top: -325px;opacity: 0;}
  100% {top: 0px;opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes cycle2 {
  0% {top: -325px;opacity: 0;}
  16% {top: -325px;opacity: 0;}
  20% {top: 0px;opacity: 1;}
  24% {top: 0px; opacity: 1;}
  36% {top: 0px; opacity: 1;z-index: 0;}
  40% {top: 325px;opacity: 0;z-index: 0;}
  41% {top: -325px;opacity: 0;z-index: -1;}
  100% {top: -325px;opacity: 0;z-index: -1;}
}

@keyframes cycle3 {
  0% {top: -325px;opacity: 0;}
  36% {top: -325px;opacity: 0;}
  40% {top: 0px;opacity: 1;}
  44% {top: 0px;opacity: 1;}
  56% {top: 0px;opacity: 1;}
  60% {top: 325px; opacity: 0;z-index: 0;}
  61% {top: -325px;opacity: 0;z-index: -1;}
  100% {top: -325px;opacity: 0; z-index: -1;}
}

@keyframes cycle4 {
  0% {top: -325px;opacity: 0;}
  56% {top: -325px;opacity: 0;}
  60% {top: 0px;opacity: 1;}
  64% {top: 0px;opacity: 1;}
  76% {top: 0px;opacity: 1;z-index: 0;}
  80% {top: 325px;opacity: 0;z-index: 0;}
  81% {top: -325px;opacity: 0;z-index: -1;}
  100% {top: -325px;opacity: 0;z-index: -1;}
}

@keyframes cycle5 {
  0% {top: -325px;opacity: 0;}
  76% {top: -325px;opacity: 0;}
  80% {top: 0px;opacity: 1;}
  84% {top: 0px;opacity: 1;}
  96% {top: 0px;opacity: 1;z-index: 0;}
  100% {top: 325px;opacity: 0;z-index: 0;}
}

.progress-bar {
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  width: 680px;
  height: 5px;
  background: #000;
  animation: fullexpand 25s ease-out infinite;
}


@keyframes fullexpand {
  
  0%, 20%, 40%, 60%, 80%, 100% {width: 0%;opacity: 0;}

  4%,24%,44%,64%,84% {width: 0%;opacity: 0.3;}

  16%,36%,56%,76%,96% {width: 100%;opacity: 0.7;}

  17%,77%,97% {width: 100%;opacity: 0.3;}

  18%,38%,58%,78%,{opacity: 0;}
}

#slider4 .tooltip {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  width: 300px;
  height: 60px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 75px;
  left: -320px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#slider4 .tooltip h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 60px;
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}

#slider4 li#list1:hover .tooltip,
#slider4 li#list2:hover .tooltip,
#slider4 li#list3:hover .tooltip,
#slider4 li#list4:hover .tooltip,
#slider4 li#list5:hover .tooltip {
  left: 0px;
}

#slider4:hover li,
#slider4:hover .progress-bar {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper4">
  <div id="content-slider">
    <div id="slider4">
      <div id="mask">
        <ul>
          <li id="list1" class="animation1">
            <a href=""><img src="http://js.seocn.info/up_pic/js/201312/1533/images/img_1.jpg" alt="Couqar"></a>
            <div class="tooltip">
              <h1>Couqar</h1>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li id="list2" class="animation2">
            <a href=""><img src="http://js.seocn.info/up_pic/js/201312/1533/images/img_2.jpg" alt="Lions"></a>
            <div class="tooltip">
              <h1>Lions</h1>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li id="list3" class="animation3">
            <a href=""><img src="http://js.seocn.info/up_pic/js/201312/1533/images/img_3.jpg" alt="Snowalker"></a>
            <div class="tooltip">
              <h1>Snowalker</h1>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li id="list4" class="animation4">
            <a href=""><img src="http://js.seocn.info/up_pic/js/201312/1533/images/img_4.jpg" alt="Howling"></a>
            <div class="tooltip">
              <h1>Howling</h1>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li id="list5" class="animation5">
            <a href=""><img src="http://js.seocn.info/up_pic/js/201312/1533/images/img_5.jpg" alt="Sunbathing"></a>
            <div class="tooltip">
              <h1>Sunbathing</h1>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="progress-bar"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### 1. Update your html

Firstly, add a sixth `li` tag for your new image after the last `li` tag in your `html` as follows:

```html
<!-- Provide a new value for 'id' and 'class' attributes and set the values as shown below -->
<li id="list6" class="animation6">
    <!--
        1. Add the path to your new image in the 'src' attribute of the `img` tag below.
        2. Describe your new image in the 'alt' attribute of the `img` tag below.
        3. Update the text in the `h1` tag below as required.
    -->
    <a href=""><img src="/the/path/to/new/image" alt="Description goes here"></a>
    <div class="tooltip">
        <h1>some new text goes here</h1>
    </div>
</li>
```

#### 2. Update your CSS

All of the animation keyframes should be updated to handle the 6th image.

#### Full example:

The complete revised code can be found here [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zt3d2duj/14/).

NOTE: You just need to add the path to your new image in the `img` tags 'src' attribute (line 44 of the html):